# Remove kitchen sink drain pipes

Tags: pipe, kitchen-sink

I am trying to remove the kitchen sink to replace it. Its drain pipes are showed in the following photo:
[image]

Anyone know how to remove these pipes from the sink? It doesn't look like I can turn the part that connects the pipes and the sink.

Comment: Exactly which fitting(s) are you trying to disconnect? How permanent a disconnection are you making (i.e. cutting will do the trick nicely, but be inconvenient if you want to reassemble when you're done)? Have you actually _tried_ unscrewing any of the fittings?

Comment: Any fitting that helps me remove the sink. I would like to reuse the pipes, so cutting may not be the best option. In all the video tutorials that I have watched, people always remove the fitting that connects the pipe and the sink only. But it doesn't look like it is possible here.

Comment: You can probably spin out the drain housing from inside the sink. I've never seen this type of pipe before. Any brand names visible?

Comment: The sink's brand is STALA (a Finnish brand)

Comment: I meant on the pipes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the company that sold the sink, and they said that the pipe is attached to bottom of the sink with a screw. So the pipe could be removed as in this photo:
[image]

Comment: Ah! So you were trying to remove the _drain_ from the _sink_ so you could replace the sink! Unfortunately, that wasn't particularly clear from your question, especially since you showed us pictures of the plumbing under the sink, only. Yes, this would be the standard way of doing it. (In some, you unscrew the entire strainer basket, not just a bolt in the center.) Please be sure to accept your answer so others know that this is wrapped up.